# Нужна запятая? Сомнения

Tags: запятые

> Являясь девушкой(,) отнюдь не бескрасотной, я многое могу рассказать-таки о парнях.

Comment: Если есть пауза, то оборот имеет значение добавления, то есть выступает в качестве дополнительной информации. Если информация важная, запятая не ставится. Вопрос мне нравится, плюс от меня.

Comment: Нету слова "бескрасотный", особенно в таком смысле! Не нужна запятая, как говорят, от слова совсем.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Запятая **НЕ СТАВИТСЯ однозначно:**

*Являясь девушкой **отнюдь не "бескрасОтной"**, // я многое могу рассказать-таки о парнЯх.*

Ударение уходит с существительного **на определение** **в конец** деепричастного оборота, произношение однозначное. Здесь две фонетические фразы.

**Семантика.** Смысл не в том, что-то кто является девушкой, а в том, что девушкой достаточно красивой.  Это **смысловой центр** высказывания.